# List all the repositories relying on as specific GitHub repository/library/dependency

Tags: php, github, version-control, composer-php, repository

Is there a way to discover all the public GitHub repositories that have a specific repository *Foo/Bar* as dependency?

I am interested in PHP context (so mostly related to *Composer*).

I wonder if there is some Composer-specific (maybe relying on *Packagist*?) or some generic solution.

Comment: Maybe now that GitHub provides the *Used By* count straight forward with the repositories. This might just be easy to infer for explicit dependencies. e.g. https://github.com/apache/commons-lang

Answer (score 2):

Given your specific requirements, one way I have done this in the past is with [Google's GitHub Data for BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/github).

For example, this query will return all repositories that have a `composer.lock` file committed with `Foo/Bar` in it.

```sql
SELECT f.repo_name
FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.files] f
JOIN [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.contents] c
  ON f.id = c.id
WHERE f.path = 'composer.lock'
  AND c.content LIKE '%"name": "Foo/Bar"%'
```

Now this has some issues, such as:

- Some packages don't commit the `composer.lock` so you could also check for the direct dependency in `composer.json` but that's not going to give you 100% of the results.
- Depending on the uniqueness of the package name `Foo/Bar` there's a chance for this string to appear elsewhere in the lock file. You may want to tweak the query.
- These queries take a *long* time to run.
- Google doesn't provide a whole lot of bandwidth quota for their free plan, so you may find yourself only being able to run a few free queries per month. Make sure you practice your queries on the smaller sample dataset before running on the full size dataset.
- If application `Fred` depends on library `baz` and `baz` depends on `Foo/Bar` do you count that as 2 dependents or just 1 with a transitive dependency? This query will count those as 2 if both `Fred` and `baz` have committed a `composer.lock` file.

Nevertheless, it's a starting point to have some sort of an idea of the scope of use for a library.